# Local library module dependency kotlin multiplatform

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Can I include local library module on the android sourceset in kotlin multiplatform?
If so, how do we do that?
I have tried adding

```
api(project(":local-library-one"))
api(project(":local-library-two"))
```

in android source-set of `build.gradle.kts` file.
It fails.

Comment: Hi, @Tushar! Did my answer solve your question? If so, please accept it. Otherwise, let me know if you have any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your "local-library" multiplatform too. It can be only targeted to android, so you don't need to modify anything but build.gradle file, something like this:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
}


android {
    // your setup
}

kotlin {
    android()
    sourceSets {
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                // your deps
            }
        }
    }
}
```